# Can this 'than' be replaced by 'from'?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> [A] “No sooner had I sat down ***than*** there was a loud knock on the door.” ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/than))

The primary function of this word, *than*, seems to be comparing two things other than the above fixed expression that shows one thing happens straight after another. From this, I got wondering if I could use next expression: “[B] No sooner had I sat down ***from*** there being a loud knock on the door” - for Longman’s advanced dictionary says ‘*from*’ is “[***comparing***] *used when you are comparing things*…” What I wanted to know is not whether [B] can substitute [A] breaking the stereotype, but [B] itself can be used.

If it can, is this also possible?:
“Lovers may kill their own love story for no other reason ***from*** that they are unable to tolerate the uncertainty. (On Love, by Alain de Botton)” - the original ***than*** is replaced into ***from***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this won't work.

*From* is not used in comparisons but in *distinctions*: it appears only with a handful of verbs (and their derivatives) whose the sense is that one entity is explicitly set *apart **from*** another:

- A differs from B.  *or* A is different from B.
- We distinguish A from B. *or* *A is distinguished from B.
- He distanced his opinions from hers. *or* His opinions were distant from hers.

But the pattern is idiomatic; it cannot be extended to other verbs.